# Empty gameobjects in a scene as hierarchy separators

Tags: unity-game-engine

Does it affect a Unity project's performance in any way if I add a bunch of empty gameobjects in the form of dotted lines (in my hierarchy window) to separate my scene content?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBeDj.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, an empty gameobject just has a transform but without any renderer or other logic. The overhead is so low you can treat it as being non existant. You could even disable those gameobjects if you really want, but it does not matter.

I often use empty gameobjects to structure the scene, as do a lot of developers. So go ahead. And if you're really worried, just run a test like this guy has done; https://answers.unity.com/questions/489354/performance-overhead-for-empty-game-objects.html

Edit; like kuchuchy pointed out, you can mark a gameobject as editoronly.
You can do so by applying the editorOnly tag to the gameobject. Also see:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tags.html

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can add the tag  "Editor Only" to the GameObject so they don't make it to your build.